# Linq Enumerable with Grouping and Aggregate into datatable or list

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to use LINQ to retrieve records based on group aggregate and put the results into datatable.

**Table (name : rstable)**

```
RSNo        Type
------------------
Rs01      |  1  |     
Rs02      |  5  |   
Rs01      |  2  |  
Rs01      |  1  |  
Rs02      |  5  |  
Rs02      |  5  |  
Rs01      |  2  |  
Rs02      |  5  |      
------------------
```

**Sql command and output :**

```
select rsno,type,count(type) as cnt from rstable group by rsno,type

rsno   type   cnt
-----------------
Rs01     1     2
Rs01     2     2
Rs02     5     4
-----------------
```

**Trying using LINQ :**

```
Have created a datatable :

DataTable dttypes = new DataTable();
dttypes.Columns.Add("rsno", typeof(String));
dttypes.Columns.Add("type", typeof(int));
dttypes.Columns.Add("cnt", typeof(int));
```

Here dtresrep is a datatable which holds the entries from sql table

```
var typeinfo = from typerow in dtresrep.AsEnumerable()
               group 1 by 
                     new { 
                             rsno = typerow.Field<String>("rsno"), 
                             type  = typerow.Field<int>("type") 
                         } into typegrp
               select new { 
                            typegrp.Key.rsno, 
                            typegrp.Key.type, 
                            cnt = typegrp.Count() 
                          };
```

Then trying to put into datatable.

```
foreach (var t in typeinfo)
    dttypes.Rows.Add(t.rsno, t.type, t.cnt);
```

This raises a Cast exception. "Specified Cast not valid."  Please guide.

Comment: include the exception message.

Comment: [System.InvalidCastException] = {"Specified cast is not valid."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this , as its `[System.InvalidCastException] = {"Specified cast is not valid."}` it error related to type mismatch between DataBase and .net moslty in this case it's related to `integer` type

```
var typeinfo = (from typerow in dtresrep.AsEnumerable()
                 group typerow by 
                 new { 
                      resno = typerow["resno"] == DBNull.Value ? '' : typerow["resno"].toString() , 
                      type  = Convert.ToInt32(typerow["type"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : typerow["type"]) 
                     } 
                    into typegrp
                    select new { 
                            typegrp.Key.resno, 
                            typegrp.Key.type, 
                            cnt = typegrp.Count() 
                          }).ToList();
```

For adding new row in data table code shold be like

```
DataTable dttypes = new DataTable();
dttypes.Columns.Add("rsno", typeof(String));
dttypes.Columns.Add("type", typeof(int));
dttypes.Columns.Add("cnt", typeof(int));

foreach (var t in typeinfo)
{
  //you need to add row like this i.e. by calling NewRow() method
  //this can be issue in you code 
    row = dttypes.NewRow();
    row["rsno"] = t.rsno;
    row["type"] = t.type;
    row["cnt"] = t.cnt;
    dttypes.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: I tried using 'typerow' already.   Changed to 1 based upon an example in some link online.   Both the ways results in Cast Exception. "Specified Cast not valid.

Comment: Yes, Iam getting the error on the LINQ query itself

Comment: @Priya - is there any possiblity that you get null from datatable

Comment: If i dont use the 'ToList()' at the end then query is fine but error occurs during foreach loop.

Comment: @Priya - i think you must check for null value ...and replace value accordingly please check updated linq by me..let me know if there is issue

Comment: @Priya - tolist is just method to execute query immediatly ... you can remove it if you dont want it ... its realted to concept linq deffered execution :http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2010/02/linq-deferred-execution.html

Comment: In the datatable there is no null values in the two columns rsno and type.

Comment: @Priya - there is error related to conversion so i did it in my query , can you please have try that query

Comment: Brilliant !!  Your updated code worked perfectly for me. There are no nulls in the datatable though.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Priya - welcome ..so there is issue of converting value ..may be database column type is not matching with datatype of .net

Comment: oh, ok.  will check the datatypes.  Thanks for the link too.  Got some light on working of LINQ.  Thanks for your help @Pranay Rana

Comment: @Priya - you can go to my blog there is stuff related to linq can help you  , here is linq stuff : http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/search/label/LINQ

Comment: Yes, will have a look in there too.  Thank you.